# Xamarin Android round corner border with color ImageView

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-imageview

I am rendering GridView with custom layout using BaseAdapter. My view contains ImageView and TextView below ImageView. For ImageView I want to set rounded corner border with black color.

I tried few suggestions from community answers.

1. Create drawable with rounded border and set it as background to ImageView.
2. Wrap ImageView into FrameLayout with another dummy ImageView which will work as frame, and set border drawable as background to it.
3. Create RoundedBitmap using RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory and set border drawable as background to it.

In all above cases I am not getting effect I suppose to get.
The Image border only overlaps with image.

In #3 problem is border and rounded bitmap corners are not exactly matching to each other. I am not sure how to do it to support multiple screen sizes and densities [see here](http://screencast.com/t/SHwVOmdi)

If I create rounded bitmap using code then it has serious memory issue:
[more details, see comments.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3292810) 
[Further details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26342897)

For option **3** 
Code:

```
internal void SetImageWithRoundCorners(int imageResID, Context context)
{
    Resources res = context.Resources;
    Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(res, imageResID);
    RoundedBitmapDrawable dr = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.Create(res, src);
    dr.CornerRadius = 50.0f;
    ImgTopicIcon.SetImageDrawable(dr);
}
```

round_border_corner.xml

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />
     <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
     <corners android:radius="@dimen/GVImgRoundCornerRad" />
     <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff000000" />
</shape>
```

Grid_Custom_Item.xml

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImgCategoryIcon" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/round_corner_border"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:id="@+id/TxtCategoryName"
    android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Expected result:
http://screencast.com/t/6hd8moeTgqAQ

Output:
http://screencast.com/t/WVgdlyq87IU

Anyone have idea how to achieve required output without memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom ImageView to add color border on image; Here is one of my project years ago, it's a kind of circular image widget for Android OS.

```
https://github.com/avenwu/IndexImageView
```

[image: Screenshot]